# Jacobians for contour integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have a certain multi-dimensional contour integral
$$\oint dz_1 \dots \oint dz_n (...) $$
and I want to perform a complex change of variables. To be concrete, I want to define new integration variables $w_k = \prod_{i=1}^k z_i$. If these were real variables I would take the absolute value of the Jacobian. In the complex case do I take the complex modulus? (my suspicion is that this is wrong) I am also unsure of what the corresponding paths of $w_k$ in $\mathbb{C}$ would look like.